# How to find out usage of battery in my application in android

Tags: android, battery

can anybody tell How to find out usage of battery in  my application in android

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says you can register for a change event on the battery state.

You can see it at the following location:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED

Answer (score 0):

You can get the battery info using BatteryManager.

Check out this [Battery Info](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2010/09/detect-battery-info.html) link.